# ClickOnce installation failed to open

Tags: visual-studio-2017, hosting, clickonce

Impossible to start application after publish, the error returned:

> Открывающий тег "meta" в позиции 14 строки 2 не соответствует закрывающему тегу "head"., строка 2, позиция 82

Answer (score 0):

The reason of error was that publish location and installation folder was pointed to different domains (even when fisically it is same, one redirects to another).
So to fix, use native domain name in both paths.